# Query needed for neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

Hey guys i needed some help in framing this query in neo4j.

Rank all artists (music artists) by the unique number of listening users, display the top 5.

Thanks

Graph is like this:

```
(User)-[:LISTENS_TO{weight:1212}]->(artists),
(User)-[:TAGS]->(artists),
(User)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(friend)
```

Query that i think might work :

```
match (m : user) - [l : listnto ] - > a : aryist
return count (distinct (m ) )as listncount , a.name order by lostencount desc limit {5}
```

Comment: What does your graph look like- how are artists related to users? What query have you tried?

Comment: (User)-[:LISTENS_TO{weight:1212}]->(artists), (User)-[:TAGS]->(artists),(User)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(friend)  I was thinking of this: match (m : user) - [l : listnto ] - > a : artist
return count (distinct (m ) )as listncount , a.name
 order by lostencount desc limit {5}  but i'm not sure.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Apart from the typos in your query, it looks fine. What is not working?

Comment: The count value returned is incorrect .

Comment: Please share a sample of your graph at http://console.neo4j.org/?init=0

Answer (score 2):

Created a small graph sample here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ujhh0x

The query

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:LISTENS_TO]->(a:Artist)
RETURN a.name,count(DISTINCT u) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

returns artists ordered by the number of unique listeners.

Comment: The query should end with `LIMIT 5`, to display at most 5.